# Create a 1D array of 1D arrays in Python

Tags: python, numpy

How can I create a 1D array of 1D array in python? That is, something like:

```
a = [array([0]) array([1]) array([2]) array([3])]
```

If I create a list of arrays and cast it, I obtain a matrix:

```
a = [array([1]), array([2])]
b = np.asarray(a)
```

then b.shape = (2,1) but if i reshape it:

```
c = np.asarray(a)
```

then c = array([1, 2]) which is an array of ints.

Is there any way to avoid this? It is worth noting that the inner arrays have shape (1,).

Comment: What is the difference between an array of arrays and a matrix?

Comment: Or a list of arrays, when the size of the arrays is not constant?

Comment: What dtypes do you want?

Comment: @Scott An array of arrays has 1 dimension (X,) and is filled of arrays of 1 dimension (Y,). It is hard to get if Y=1.

Comment: @hpaulj I think in this case the dtypes of the outer array would be object and the dtypes of the inner, integers.

Comment: If all subarrays have the same length, you have to create an ` p.empty` array of right size and object dtype.  Then fill it with the arrays (or lists).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, found. The solution is to create an empty array with dtype object and assign there a list of arrays.

```
a = [array([1]), array([2])]
b = np.empty(len(a), dtype=object)
b[:] = a
```

And now b = array([array([1]), array([2])], dtype=object)

Comment: Just for curiosity sake, but why do you need this? What is the difference with the presented solutions?

Comment: I overload a function and the ones that call it expect to receive an array of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:

```
ans = [np.array([i]) for i in range(4)]
print (ans)
```

**Output**

```
[array([0]), array([1]), array([2]), array([3])]
```

Comment: Sadly, this is a list of 1D arrays, not an array of arrays.

Comment: Oh, I just tried to give you something to reproduce your output. You can put `np.array( )` around the `ans` to get the final array. Try it if that's what you want

Comment: Then you'll get a 2D array, with dimensions (4,1) instead of (4,)

Comment: Well in that case you will have to elaborate more clearly what you want.

Comment: Thanks, I would like to create a 1D array of 1D arrays. Not a 1D array of integers, not a 2D array of 1D arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can either have a **matrix-like list**, when the shape of the arrays is all the same:

```
matrix_like_list = np.array([np.arange(10) for i in range(3)])

>>> array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
           [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
           [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
```

with shape `(3, 10)`, or you can have a **list of arrays** when the size of at least one array is different:

```
list_of_arrays = np.array([np.arange(np.random.randint(10)) for i in range(3)])

>>> array([array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]),
       array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])], dtype=object)
```

The resulting object will have shape `(3,)`.

*There are no other options.*

Comment: Hi @LucaCappelletti, Sandly your options does't work either. For 1 dimensional arrays, a casting is done: np.array([np.arange(1) for i in range(3)]) has shape (3,1)

Comment: As said, those arrays have constant size, therefore are treated as a matrix. No other option is available and I don't understand the issue you are facing. If you were to describe thoroughly the problem wr might figure out a solution for you.

Comment: It is different in numpy a 1D array (that has shape (X,)) than a 2D array (with shape (X,Y)). Hence, it is not the same a 1D array of 1D arrays, that is, an array with dimensions (A,) filled of objects of type array with shapes (B,) than an array with shape (A,B). For instance, if the object is called "p" in the former you can do: len(p[0]), but not in the latter, as the object inside "p", if they are (1,) are casted to integers.

Comment: Could you provide in your question a code snippet to highlight this difference? I'm not sure I understand what you are saying.

Comment: The first example is an array, not a matrix.

Comment: @user3483203 could you explain me the difference?

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html, numpy actually has matrices, there is a difference

Comment: Yes, but they are treated as any ndarray, isn't it?

Comment: No. Example: `m = np.matrix([[1,2],[3,4]]), m**2 = matrix([[ 7, 10], [15, 22]]). a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]]), a**2 = array([[ 1,  4], [ 9, 16]])`

Comment: Oh, thank you, I always done that automatically and never thought of the difference.